# Web service hosted with Tomcat 8: Java classes displayed in HTML instead of the actual text

Tags: java, tomcat

I need to host a web service at work with Tomcat 8. The actual files for the web service come in a .war file directly from the vendor and I copy/paste them into the correct Tomcat directory.
The deployment works fine but when I open the website it would only show like the Java classes and the package but not the actual "text" behind it. Look and the screenshot and you will see what I mean.
Any idea what causes this? I have JRE 1.8 installed on the server and system variables point to the correct Java locations.

This is an industry standard software so I believe I most have done something wrong somewhere.

[image: Click to view image]

Comment: What you are seeing looks like resource bundle keys used for internationalization. My guess is that the application can't work properly without expanding the WAR file because whatever i18n technique the application is using can't load the resource bundles (the actual text) from within the WAR file. You should ask the original vendor what's going on, because this isn't your fault.

Comment: NB This does not constitute displaying Java classes.